# Import csv file to SharePoint List containing Lookup using client side powershell

Tags: csv, powershell, sharepoint

I have a csv file and I was able to import data using client side powershell to SP Lists containing single line of text and multiline but I was unable to import lookup value.How to import that column in csv to lookup column.(That is how to set the id of lookup dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

```
#For Lookup values: Lookup Parent List
$DepartmentList=$web.Lists["Department"]

   #Get the Lookup Item from Parent List
   $LookupItem = $departmentList.Items | Where-Object { $_.Item("Title") -eq $row.Department}

if($LookupItem -ne $null)
{
         $deptLookup = New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPFieldLookupValue($LookupItem.ID,$row.Department)
}

     #Set the Lookup field value
     $item["Department"] = $deptLookup

   $item.Update()


Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/import-from-csv-file-to-sharepoint-list-using-powershell.html#ixzz40VmbNqi0
```

Where $row variable is csv row.